# How can you let Next 13’s server components get access to data stored in state?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, fetch-api, server-side-rendering, next.js13

I know the whole purpose of Next 13 is to separate server and client side so the question won’t make much sense now but here’s my motivation:

I want to make a drag and drop crypto widget app using React and Next js. My idea is to let users drag certain charts to a grid and subsequently let them drag coins to said charts. After exiting editing mode or whatever, these charts will then display data about the coins. Obviously, these widgets will have to be client components as they will have to store their position, which coins they hold etc. in state.

Furthermore, I want to take full advantage of the Next 13 fetch features. This means that after you have exited editing mode, it would be smart to display the widgets as server components as after that, these widgets aren’t interactive anymore.

One problem though, how would you get the info such as the widget’s position and which coins the user has dragged into it, to the alternate server component version of the widget? Knowing that server components cannot consume context themselves and therefore have to rely on client components.

I have scoured through the docs and one thing is very clear: you can’t import server components into client components. You can only pass them as children or props which means they already have to be rendered, which means they already need to know which api endpoint to fetch i.e. for what coin to fetch the right data.

You see how this becomes a chicken and egg situation.

I have thought about just fetching all data at page load and storing it in state but this seems very cumbersome as crypto data, especially historical data can be relatively large. Not to mention having to fetch it for all coins.

I also considered using SWR as recommened by next 13 in the docs. My question then becomes: Is SWR on par with Next 13's fetch features?

Answer (score 0):

I would create two separate components for this:

1. `ChartDesigner` which the user interacts with to design a chart. This component is highly interactive and lives purely on the client. The output of the component is a JSON structure that describes the final design, which includes positions of elements, applicable coins, etc.
2. `ChartRenderer` which is responsible for rendering the chart. It uses the "design" JSON from the designer component and a dataset to render the final chart. This component can be rendered both on the server and the client.